# Postgresql выборка с учетом координат

Tags: postgresql

Есть интересная задача, над которой ломаю голову уже пару дней. Существует база данных с пользователями и их координатами (долгота и широта в отдельных полях). Необходимо написать sql выборку, которая покажет пользовтаелей находящихся в выбранном диапазоне на карте.

Я сделал возможность отрисовки на карте произвольной области, после чего получаю массив с несколькими координатами. В зависимости от нарисованной фигуры количество координат может меняться.

Каким образом можно, имея множество координат, написать sql запрос и выбрать только тех пользователей, которые входят в этот диапазон? 
Может кто сталкивался с подобным, помогите, плиз, в какую сторону смотреть?

Postresql 9.1 без возможности обновления..

Comment: Установите расширение postgis и пользуйтесь его функциями

Comment: Извиняюсь, что сразу не указал версию postgresql. Postgis не подойдет..

Comment: Используйте postgis. Postgis появился в районе postgresql 7.3, а на 9.1 встанет даже не слишком древний postgis 2.2. https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostgreSQLPostGIS

Comment: Без postgis вам придется написать функцию на Pl/sql, которая принимает конкретные координаты и решает геометрическую задачу на вхождение точки в область. после чего вызывать эту функцию в запросе. Производительность такого решения будет никакая, потому что по обычным индексам поиск работать не сможет и запросу надо будет пересмотреть всю таблицу пользователей и для каждого пользователя решить задачу по вхождению

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем за советы. С postgis возникли сложности при установке, поэтому пришлось отказаться от его использования. Решение для круговой области без использования postgis:

```
    $rad = $radius/1000; // радиус круга в км
    $R = 6371;  // радиус Земли в км

    $maxLat = $lat + rad2deg($rad/$R);
    $minLat = $lat - rad2deg($rad/$R);
    $maxLon = $lon + rad2deg(asin($rad/$R) / cos(deg2rad($lat)));
    $minLon = $lon - rad2deg(asin($rad/$R) / cos(deg2rad($lat)));

    $dLat = deg2rad($lat);
    $dLon = deg2rad($lon);

    $sql = <<<sql
        Select *
            From (
                Select "siteUserId", lat, lon
                From "getGeoStat"
                Where lat Between $minLat And $maxLat
                  And lon Between $minLon And $maxLon
            ) As users
            Where acos(sin($dLat)*sin(radians(lat)) + cos($dLat)*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(lon)- $dLon)) * $R < $rad
sql;
```

Спасибо https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html